# creating WebRTC data channels after peerConnection established

Tags: webrtc

Is there a way to create data channel when peer connection already established?

Here is what I'm doing:

```
peerConnection.onstatechange = function(event){
        var state = peerConnection.readyState;
        console.log('state changed to : '+state);
        if(state==='stable'){
            console.log('connection is stable');
            var dataChannel = peerConnection.createDataChannel('test',{reliable: false});
            dataChannel.onopen = function(){
                console.log('data channel opened');
                dataChannel.send('hello data channel');
            };
            peerConnection.ondatachannel = function(event){
                console.log('ondatachannel event fire ',event);
            };              
        }
    };
```

And it gives me the following output:

```
state changed to : have-local-offer
state changed to : stable 
connection is stable
```

1. How to make sure that connection is really established? I found [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=940) that `stable` state is equal to `active` sate.
2. `onopen` event does not fire for some reason, so I'm still not sure that connection is established.

If you need some more code, tell me.

EDIT:
I added `onnegotiationneeded` event handler and now `peerConnection.ondatachannel` is firing, but the channel is in `connecting` state

Comment: sort of, but it is still very unstable

Answer (score 10):

You might have run into the same problem as I have. Apparently you must add a datachannel before you create an offer, and if you want to add a stream you will need to create a new offer/answer and renegotiate. According to the W3C specs:

http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/

> In particular, if a RTCPeerConnection object is consuming a MediaStream and a track is added to one of the stream's MediaStreamTrackList objects, by, e.g., the add() method being invoked, the RTCPeerConnection object must fire the "negotiationneeded" event. Removal of media components must also trigger "negotiationneeded".

However, the negotiationneeded event is not yet built in FF (and I think in Chrome to) so that's why things might behave a bit erratically.